# Can I know when people open a link on my site in new tab?

Tags: php, session, tabs, browser-history

What I want to know is when people click a link on my site (internal link - not to another websites) if they just clicked it or if the ctrl-clicked it (or right click - open in new tab).

I use PHP.

So example:
Person is on page1 and click on link for page2.
When they are on page2 I want to know where they came from (_server['http_referer'] gives me that) but I also want to know if they opened the page in new window/tab. I need to know this because of history back button on the page.

Reason for this is to know the browsing history around the site - I create session to keep track of browsing history (so that I can go one page back, two pages back or three pages back at any given time) but I don't want the sessions to conflict between tabs so that each tab has it's own browsing history. Thats why I need to create new session for each tab opened.

---

What I have found as a possible solution to my problem is to use javascript similar to this:

```
<script>
var history_status = history.length;
var referrer_site = document.referrer;

if(history_status > 1 && referrer_site != "") {
    alert(referrer_site);
} else {
    alert('No referrer site');
}
</script>
```

I need to change it a little bit more but this was my first demo to check if it works (and it did)

I first need to find what browser user is using because history_status gives 0 for the first page in history  when you use IE but 1 if you are using Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: You could use javascript `onready` and the `history` object to check if there is any history. If so, the user just clicked the link and you can show/hide the history elements you created with PHP.

Comment: Browsers already have "go back X pages" functionality built in (usually triggered by holding the back button down). Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Quentin you are not understanding what I am trying to do. The user is not supposed to decide how many pages he goes back.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt sound like good user experience. Back buttons and allowing people to open new tabs is something users expect to behave in a certain way. Personally i would find it frustrating. What is the point in a new tab if they cant form their own unique browsing history just for that tab?

If you really really wanted to do this. Create a cookie with a number, on every page load bump up thr number and store the page URL in your database for that session. On page load, pull in thr history and load it into your browser history via JavaScript. Eeek.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess I am not describing my problem with enough details.

I also have found some way I can hack this into my system with javascript.

Reason for this is because I have form that you fill out, after that form comes another form but when you save that I want to take you two sites back and thats why I save the referrer sites in the session.

Answer (score 1):

*Since the question is really old I will illustrate the question to make it more clear. Hopefully, I didn't also misunderstand the question asked.*


Case:
 -  I have a website. This website has a form. The form is located on 2 (or more) webpages: *Form p001* and *Form p002* ( ... *Form pX*). 
 - On the page with *Form p001* there is a button with the link to the page where *Form p002* is located.
 - On the page with the last part of the form, which in my case is *Form p002*, there is the submit button. The submit button will redirect you to whichever page **on my website** you were when you clicked a button that sent you to the page *Form p001* or whichever page on my website you were before you loaded the page *Form p001*.
 - Imagine the following 3 *example* cases (there are obviously more than 3 possible cases, just to keep it short).
[image]

> - Example 01: I am on *Page X* on my website. There is the button to the form, I click on this and go to the form page part 1 *(Form p001)*. I click on the button **Part-02** to go to the page with part 2 of the form *(Form p002)*. When I finish the second part of the form, I click on submit. This will redirect me to *Page X* on my website
> - Example 02: After looking around on several pages on my website I am now on *Page Y*. There is the button to the form, I right-click on this and open the form page part 1 *(Form p001)* inside a new tab (tab 02). I click on the button **Part-02** to go to the page with part 2 of the form *(Form p002)*. When I finish the second part of the form, I click on submit. This will redirect me back to *Page Y* on my website (inside tab 02).
> - Example 03: After looking around on several pages on my website I am now on *Page Z*. There is the button to the form, I right-click on this and open the form page part 1 *(Form p001)* inside a new tab (tab 02). I right-click on the button **Part-02** to go to the page with part 2 of the form *(Form p002)* inside a new tab (tab 03). When I finish the second part of the form, I click on submit. This will redirect me back to *Page Z* on my website (inside tab 03).

*If the person has loaded the first page of the form (Form p001), by putting the link of the form page directly in the LOCATION/ADDRESS bar of the browser inside a new tab or window, then we assume you will be redirected to the home page. This is not reallly relevant to this question tho.*


Answer:
You can use **window.localStorage** and **document.referrer**
You can use window.localStorage to store the original-page, the page on my website where I was before going to the first page of the form. Test the following codes.

**somePageOnMyWebsite.html** (Page X, Y or Z)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A Random page on My Website</h1>
    <p>My paragraph.</p>
    <a type="button" href="formp001.html" target="_blank">Click to form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**formp001.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var originalPage = document.referrer;
            if( originalPage != null)
                window.localStorage.setItem("redirectPage", originalPage);
            else
                window.localStorage.setItem("redirectPage", "");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form p001</h1>
    <form action="formp002.html" target="_self" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to Form p002" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**formp002.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if (window.localStorage.getItem("redirectPage") === null || window.localStorage.getItem("redirectPage") === ""){
                // The form was not accessed by clicking on a link on a page on my website, so just redirect to my homepage ...
                document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")[0].setAttribute("action", "./hometest.html");
            } else{
                document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")[0].setAttribute("action", window.localStorage.redirectPage);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form p002</h1>
    <form action="#" target="_self" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**hometest.html** (home page of my website)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
    <p>My home</p>
</body>
</html>
```

*My answer is based on birgir's comment on **Luc's** answer.*